# LOGISTICS REGRESSION FOR PREDICTING NON-BINARY OUTCOME WITH TIME SERIES I THINK?

Tags: time-series, self-study, logistic, multiple-regression, forecasting

What will I do if I have data of specific 50 employees about their gender and age and I want to know if these independent variables really affect the dependent variable which is Medical Class Type (Class A, B, C, D). Class A-very fit to Class D-not fit to work. I have the yearly data from 2012 to 2016 and I want to know what will be the possible Class Type they will have in the next 2 years perhaps. I dont know if I will use logistics regression or autoregressive time series or both. Somebody please help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Think a bit more about what you want. I know that is difficult without knowing what can be done, but some of this you need to do yourself to avoid answers like "go read an entire book".

Comment: Maybe ordinal logistic regression could help?  Think about it ...

Comment: This was clear enough that it alreadty got a (probably helpful) answer, so why close?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to go on here, but here are a few points:

- Your dependent variable is an ordered categorical variable.  That suggests using *ordered* logistic regression.  Logistic regression isn't appropriate, because the dependent variable isn't binary.  Multinomial logistic regression is applicable, but ignores the ordering (presumably class A is more fit to work than class B, which is more fit to work than class C, and so forth), and will require many more parameters, with a corresponding loss of efficiency.
- Autoregressive isn't a bad thought, but it's not a time series. It's panel data. You'd probably want to use the previous year's Medical Class Type as a (categorical) independent variable.
- You have two goals here, as far as I can tell: inference (whether gender and age affect the class type) and prediction.  The inference part is easier (test significance of the corresponding parameters).  Predicting probabilities of each class a year out (i.e. for 2017) is also easy, once you have the parameter estimates.  Predicting two years out is a little more difficult, but you can work it out using basic properties of conditional probabilities etc.

Some references on ordered logistic regression are Paul Allison's *Logistic Regression Using SAS*, and Long and Freese's *Regression Models for Categorical Dependent Variables Using Stata*.